# Excel table type standard filter imperfect javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, handsontable

So I have a ui pretty much the same as what your find in excel standard filter. (screenshot is arbitrary example unrelated to code examples)

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to evaluate the collection of conditions.
My code checks the condition against the cell and I'm adding a boolean property to show the results of the condition

```
var filteredData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var row = data[i];
var rowObj = constructRowObject(
 pm, row);
 var condResArr = [];
 for (var r = 0; r < uiSelectionResultsArr.length; r++) {
   var cond = uiSelectionResultsArr[r],
   cellValue = rowObj[cond.colName],
   expType = cond.expression,
   value = cond.value;
   if(expType === "equal"){
     cond.evaluated  = (cellValue == value);
   }else if(expType === "not-equal"){
     cond.evaluated  = (cellValue != value);

   }else if(expType === "greater"){
     cond.evaluated  = (cellValue > value);

   }else if(expType === "less"){
     cond.evaluated  = (cellValue < value);
   }   
 }
 //now we have a list of booleans added to our cond objects
 //undefined group is the first one (A and D) bracketed by
 //adjacent row pairs - therefore sort by id
 var sorted =  _.sortBy(uiSelectionResultsArr, 'id'); 
}
```

So as an example of what I end up with is this

```
  [{
        "colName": "id",
        "id": 1,
        "expression": "greater",
        "value": "50",
        "evaluated": false
    }, {
        "colName": "id",
        "id": 2,
        "expression": "less",
        "value": "100",
        "operation": "and",
        "evaluated": true
    }, {
        "operation": "or",
        "id": 3,
        "colName": "id",
        "expression": "equal",
        "value": "200",
        "evaluated": false
    }]
```

Now I need to join the evaluated boolean values by their logical operators ie: the groups they are in - which are implied by the adjacent criteria rows. In this case it would be

> if (false && true) || false

This obviously false, but what I'd like to do is build this/whatever the condition expression is at runtime ... is it possible to do such a thing in javascript.

I'm not asking for criticism of the ui or even the logic, I'm just curious if you can "Evaluate an array of boolean values with logical operators at runtime"

My best guess so far is something like this but it has obvious problems.

```
$("#filter-btn").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("uiSelectionResultsArr: "+ JSON.stringify(uiSelectionResultsArr));
  //order of columns could have been moved can't just use index
  var constructRowObject = function(pm, handsonDsRow) {
    var colHeaders = pm.currentHeaders;
    var newRowObj = {};
    for (var index = 0; index < colHeaders.length; index++) {
      newRowObj[colHeaders[index]] = handsonDsRow[index];
    }
    //console.log("constructRowObject: "+ JSON.stringify(newRowObj));
    return newRowObj;
  };

  /*
  * [{"operation":"and","id":1,"colName":"id","expression":"equal","value":"500"},
  * {"operation":"or","id":2,"colName":"col5","expression":"smaller","value":"100"}]
  */
  // the filter in run per table row
  // using the condions in
  // uiSelectionResultsArr we decide
  // if each row should be in the
  // results
  var data = hot.getData();
  var filteredData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var rowObj = constructRowObject(pm, row);
    for (var r = 0; r < uiSelectionResultsArr.length; r++) {
      var cond = uiSelectionResultsArr[r],
      cellValue = rowObj[cond.colName],
      expType = cond.expression,
      value = cond.value;
      if(expType === "equal"){
        cond.evaluated  = (cellValue == value);
      }else if(expType === "not-equal"){
        cond.evaluated  = (cellValue != value);

      }else if(expType === "greater"){
        cond.evaluated  = (cellValue > value);

      }else if(expType === "smaller"){
        cond.evaluated  = (cellValue < value);
      }

    }
    console.log("uiSelectionResultsArr (after evaluated): "+JSON.stringify(uiSelectionResultsArr));
    //now we have a list of booleans added to our cond objects
    //undefined group is the first one (A and D) bracketed by
    //adjacent row pairs - therefore sort by id
    var sorted =  _.sortBy(uiSelectionResultsArr, 'id');
    //console.log("sorted: "+JSON.stringify(sorted));
    /*sorted: [{"colName":"id","id":1,"expression":"greater","value":"50","evaluated":false},
    {"colName":"id","id":2,"expression":"smaller","value":"100","operation":"and","evaluated":true},
    {"operation":"or","id":3,"colName":"id","expression":"equal","value":"200","evaluated":false}]*/
    //if (false && true) || false
    //logic is probably wrong but just:
    //group by operation
    var opgrouped = _.groupBy(uiSelectionResultsArr, 'operation');
    //console.log("op grouped: "+JSON.stringify(opgrouped));
    //add undefined group to whatever the group the second is in
    //there is only ever 1 element in the "undefined" group the top row
    if(sorted.length > 1){
      if(sorted[1].operation === "and"){
        opgrouped.and.push(opgrouped["undefined"][0]);
      }else{
        opgrouped.or.push(opgrouped["undefined"][0]);
      }
    }else{//single condition filter in which case just stick it in a new and group
      opgrouped.and = [];
      opgrouped.and.push(opgrouped["undefined"][0]);
    }
    //condense each group to single boolean each
    var condensedAnd = true, condensedOr = false;
    if(opgrouped.and){
      for(var x=0;x<opgrouped.and.length;x++){
        var cond = opgrouped.and[x];
        //console.log("opgrouped.and[x]: where x: "+x+", opgrouped.and[x]: "+JSON.stringify(opgrouped.and[x]));
        //console.log("cond.evaluated: "+cond.evaluated);
        if(cond.evaluated !== true){
          condensedAnd = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if(opgrouped.or){
      for(var y=0;y<opgrouped.or.length;y++){
        var cond = opgrouped.or[y];
        if(cond.evaluated === true){
          condensedOr = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    //condense single booleans using or
    var result;
    if(opgrouped.and && opgrouped.or){
      result = (condensedAnd || condensedOr);
    }else if(opgrouped.or){
      result = condensedOr;

    }else if(opgrouped.and){
      result = condensedAnd;
    }

    if(result === true){
      console.log("boolean result: "+result+" adding row: "+JSON.stringify(row)+" to filteredData");
      filteredData.push(row);
    }

    //if(i>10)break;//for testing
  }

  hot.loadData(filteredData);
  $.modal.close();

});
```

This logic works but I can't help feeling it's imperfect maybe someone can offer some suggestions for improvements

Comment: How do you distinguish between "(A and B) or C" and "A and (B or C)" in your UI? (This comment was harder to make readable than I expected)

Comment: And just for the record, it's probably a bad idea to use `eval` as a variable name, it's reserved and not for you! :)

Comment: Seems like you've created a GUI to make things more complicated for the user. That's typically not what they're for.

Comment: @Jonathan The gui is like excel standard filter, complicated or not it's what the user is used to

Comment: Not sure how to distinguish between "(A and B) or C" and "A and (B or C)". The requirement was to make it look like a desktop spreadsheet standard filter. I just copied the layout from Libre Calc - do you have any ideas. There don't seem to be controls in Libre Calc to group   "(A and B) or C" so am guessing there is some implied order, but it's not obvious.

Comment: Kind of complicated but you can try something like this: Use this screen only for one group of criteria. "Apply" should add this criteria and reset the inputs to add another group of criteria (probably rename it to "Add" or something). For adding the subsequent groups, you'll have to include an "and/or/and not/etc." input to chain them together. You might be able to take a couple tips from [here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx), it's a search tool for Magic cards and I think it might be something close to what you're after.

Comment: Not really worried about the ui it behaves exactly like a spreadsheet filter ui. It adds additional criteria on validation of the above row automatically. Just need to figure out how to use the opgrouped data to combine the booleans

Comment: You might have a look at [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) to see if it fits your requirements. I've used it projects and it's excellent. They have a filter plugin, though I've not tried it.

Comment: Performance is not good in DataTables, have to deal with page sizes of 100,000 rows. I'm using Handsontable